# Why doesn't my bright blue in in RGB match when I convert to CMYK?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb, color-spaces

[image][image: **enter image description here**]

I can't apply selected color in CMYK mode but can apply RGB mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply selected color"?

Comment: I select blue color as a foreground but when i fill this color on the document it seems another color that you seen on picture.

Comment: But RGB mode is no problem to apply color.

Comment: RGB has more saturated blues than CMYK which simply can not do so so far the application is emulating the papers tonal range. This is the closest you can get.

Comment: If I want to use Blue color in my design that I will print.How look like to see it ? Is it blue color or other ? Really I confused. Please you see my those screen shot.@ joojaa

Comment: Using a cmyk system you can not print that deep blue period. You will get a blue but not that saturated one. See the video in the [suggested duplicate](http://hidefcolor.com/blog/color-management/rgb-convert-cmyk-profile-color-photoshop/). You will just have toscale down your colors for printing or then use custom inks while printing, which is more expensive and wont happen on small runs. You can also use a more than 4 color printing to boost the range but those are the facts. What you want is not what you get no matter how much you want.

Comment: The RGB blue you want doesn't exist in CMYK its as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the CMYK colour space is smaller than the RGB space. So when you move from RGB to CMYK your colours are mapped to the nearest printable colour. To generalize, the RGB space has more very saturated "bright" colours. For in depth info, read up on 'additive' (RGB) and 'subtractive' (CMYK) colour.

Comment: Could you send me a blue color design ( any thing ) in CMYK mode. Which will show blue color if I print it. It seems that every dark color is become light color in CMYK mode than RGB mode, isn't it right?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you understand it better:
[image]